# Using command prompt in win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd

I just want to execute a simple command in command prompt. I know we can do that in a win32 c++ project. But, I'm dealing with some specific requirements as stated below.

1) Execute a simple command.

2) Get the output from it.

3) Hide the command prompt window (completely).

I've researched Internet and been able to accomplish the first two requirements using `popen()`. But, I doubt it is even possible to complete the third requirement using `popen()`

**EDIT:**
Here's the code which I've been using.

```
string execute(const char *cmd)
{
    shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) 
    {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe.get()) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    return result;
}
```

On running the above code, *cmd.exe* is opened. And it has no text on it. Just a plain command prompt shows up.

Comment: Tried out `system()` already? Or as you asking for windows something like `CreateProcess()` (IIRC there was an option to hide the console window)?

Comment: If you've actually tried something, post what you've tried. If you haven't tried anything yet and are just looking to form a discussion, please do that on some other site as it's really not appropriate here. As to the "hide the command prompt window" aspect you seem most troubled with... depending on the command you're thinking of running through `popen()`, there may not be any need for cmd.exe to run at all. (So, you see why you providing more details is essential here?)

Comment: [Near dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10973170/179910).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How would you propose to hide the console window using either `system` or `CreateProcess`?

Comment: @IInspectable I think it's some attribute like `WORD   wShowWindow;` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable: My answer to the question I linked above shows one way to do it with `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself! After-all, its not very much tough as I thought.

Here is the [link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?400189-CreateProcess-Command-line-args) which helped me solve my problem perfectly. The reply to the thread in that link was exactly what I needed.